# Slow NFS performance on multi-user systems

Tags: networking, nfs

We're using mounted NFS drives on multiple multi-user Ubuntu systems. From times to times, the NFS read and write performance is very slow, taking many minutes to perform a simple `ls` operation. On another machine, the same `ls` operation on the same NFS drive at the same time however is very fast. Furthermore, other mounted NFS drives on the machine in question still exhibit normal speed. This issue seems to be related to the NFS client. We use the following command to mount the NFS drive:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,timeo=600,nolock,async $IP:/ /mnt/nfs
```

Up to now, I explained this with someone currently using the NFS drive extensively on that machine (reading/writing many files), thereby blocking other requests. However, given the fact that this is a per-machine issue and not NFS server related, I start to question whether there's not something we could do against it, such as choosing the correct mount options.

Does NFS support frequent read/writes (e.g., directly processing data on the network drive) or should they generally be avoided? And which mount options are preferable on a system with many users accessing the same NFS drive?